# Ключ - Значение в бинарном дереве

Tags: c++, бинарное-дерево

Есть бинарное дерево.

```
struct Collatz {
    int key;
    unsigned int value;
};

struct Node //Звено дерева
{
    Collatz x; //То, что записываем в дерево
    Node *l, *r; //Это указатели на новые звенья
};
```

Бинарное дерево заполняется случайными значениями, где value - случайной значение, а key - индекс во время добавления:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 60000; ++i) {
        my[i].value = rand() % 100000 + 1000000;
        my[i].key = i;
        add_node(my[i], Tree);
    }
```

После окончания работы с бинарным деревом его нужно вывести в том порядке, в котором значения вводились.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: вы балансируете дерево после каждой вставки? Если балансировки нет, то я как понимаю, у вас все значения будут справа и ваша задача сводиться в чтению правой ветки бинарного дерева с корнем дерева, равным 0.  Можете показать add_node, чтобы не вести догадки, как вы добавляете элемент в дерево?

Comment: Это не имеет значения: вывод для дерева будет одинаков. Это скорее вопрос эффективности, нежели вывода.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch. Если дерево не сбалансированное, то ваш вариант ответа будет выводить числа в порядке, обратном тому, которые вы добавляете. Так как у вас первым выведется лист правой ветки. А лист правой ветки будет иметь максимальный элемент.

Comment: Это с какого перепуга? Вы может не верно поняли: посмотрите еще раз, она выведет все элементы, начиная с корня, а не с последенго элемнта

Answer (score 0):

Если ваше значение - порядковый номер ввода в дерева, то никаких проблем нет, если, конечно, оно реализовано верно. Для этого потребуется рекурсия

```
print(node *i) {
    if (i->left) 
        print(i->left);
    cout << i;
    if (i->right)
        print(i->right);
}
```

Как-то так.